# How to find number of fields in each record in a file using NF and NR?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file with 100 records and each record contains different number of fields.

EX:FILE1.DAT

1 132 09 78 90

2 8788 67 22 88 77

3 17 45

......................

......................

100 25 48 99 745 256

How to find number of fields in each line/record using NF and NR in unix.

1,2,3 ..100 at starting of line/record is line/record number.

I am expecting result as below:

4

5

2

--

--

5

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you understand what `NF` and `NR` are/represent?

Comment: we use NR and NF in 'awk' command..NR- no of records, NF-no of fields

Comment: So if `NF` is the number of fields how would you print the output you are expecting with `awk`? (Hint: This is dead-simple and probably an example awk script in the manual/online.)

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple.

`awk '{print NF}' FILE1.DAT`